# svn log no results using path and revision

Tags: svn

While using svn log from command line. I am unable to specify a path and use a revision at the same time.

```
svn log svn://myrepo -l 5
```

--returns 5 results

```
svn log -l 5 -r {2014-05-01}:{2014-05-08}
```

--returns 5 results

```
svn log svn://myrepo -l 5 -r {2014-05-01}:{2014-05-08}
```

--returns 0 results

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Did you try `svn log -l 5 -r {2014-05-01}:{2014-05-08} svn://myrepo`? I am pretty sure the path is supposed to come after the options.

Comment: I did yes. Still returns 0 results.